# Loop to split dataframe base on unique value of 2 columns individually

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large single dataframe that looks similar to this

[image]

How do i do a loop through this large dataframe to split it into multiple smaller dataframe base on the unique value of both column 'RESV' and column 'TYPE'.

So you would have 12 (3x4) smaller dataframes (with 3 unique values in column 'RESV' and 4 unique values in column 'TYPE'. For example. some of these dataframes would look like as follows:-

And how to name those dataframes individually?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check with groupby

Comment: How many unique values do you have for each?

Comment: 3 unique values in column 'RESV' and 4 unique values in column 'TYPE'